# How to query the most specific type of a property

Tags: sparql, owl, description-logic

I have an `objectProperty` hierarchy. At a certain level of it, there is a sub-property `X`, which has its own sub-properties, let's say `X1` and `X2` one level below it. The actual property assertions are made using `X1` and `X2`. However, I am querying with `select * {?s :X ?o}` to get them all. What I would want to get also is the IRI of the concrete `X` descendant that was used in the assertion.

Is this achievable, and how?

*[Update 01.07]*
Just a demo:

```
@prefix : <http://test/demo#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .

:x {
    :X a owl:ObjectProperty.
    :X1 a owl:ObjectProperty ; rdfs:subPropertyOf :X .
    :X11 a owl:ObjectProperty; rdfs:subPropertyOf :X1 .
    :X12 a owl:ObjectProperty; rdfs:subPropertyOf :X1 .

    :o1 a owl:Thing.
    :o2 a owl:Thing.

    :o1 :X11 owl:Thing.
    :o2 :X12 owl:Thing.
}
```

Queries:

1)

```
prefix : <http://test/demo#>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT * FROM :x {?s :X ?o}
```

With reasoning *on* returns the facts, but no clue about the assertions. With reasoning *off*, returns nothing, as expected.
@ValerioCocchi this is not good for me.

2)

```
prefix : <http://test/demo#>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
select * FROM :x {?p rdfs:subPropertyOf* :X . ?s ?p ?o}
```

With reasoning *off*, return the information needed. @UninformedUser, thank you!

Comment: I think different systems use different ways to turn reasoning on/off.
If you turn reasoning off, then you will only see the properties that were in the initial dataset.
What triplestore are you on?

Comment: without a reasoner in the backend and just plain SPARQL (no full OWL 2 DL nor any other profile enabled): `select * {?p rdfs:subPropertyOf* :X . ?s ?p ?o}` - is it efficient? Depends on the size of the data as well as the triple store.